# I am trying to open another dialog fragment when I click on an item in a recycle viewer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog

I am trying to open another dialog fragment here is the code:

```
private  fun showList() {

    val job = Job()
    val scopeMainThread = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)
    val scopeIO = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)

    val adapter = ServerListAdapter()
    val recyclerView = binding.rvConnList

    binding.rvConnList.addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(
            activity,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
        )
    )

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)

    val serverViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this)[ServerViewModel::class.java]
    scopeIO.launch {
        val x = serverViewModel.getAll()
        scopeMainThread.launch {
            activity?.let {
                x.observe(it) { s ->
                    s?.let { it ->
                        adapter.setData(it)
                        adapter.onItemClick = {

                            SyncSovEntryFragment(Date(), it).apply {
                                setListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Set date: $year/$month/$dayOfMonth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                                activity?.let { it1 -> show(it1.supportFragmentManager, "MonthYearPickerDialog") }
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(activity, it.database, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

what I ma trying is opening another dialog fragment, is there any other way to call the supportFragmentManager in a dialog Fragment? beacause this code does not work:

activity?.let { it1 -> show(it1.supportFragmentManager, "MonthYearPickerDialog") }

thank you.

Comment: Proper to call inside your `ServerListAdapter`.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean call it from inside the adapter not onItemClick.

Comment: I am using that adapter on other activities. is there no way I can call another dialog fragment using supportFragmentManager?

Answer (score 0):

open activity or fragment inside your adapter like this

```
           holder.itemlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent;
            intent =  new Intent(context, yourfragment.class);
          
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }




    });
```

itemlayout is main layout of your recyclerview item to be clicked

Comment: Fragments cannot be created with an intent and startActivity.